# Routes confusion in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

What am I doing wrong?
I have certain buttons in my rails app. e.g 
Sports Travel Politics

When I click on **'Sports'** it take me to this route
***/tags/sports*** which is what i want but if i edit the route manually in browser from /tags/sports to ***/tags/something*** (anything after /tags/) it still works where as it should be giving error , something like route does not exist or slug does not exist.

[image]

**Model**

```
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
  before_validation :generate_slug_from_tag

  field :name, type: String
  field :slug, type: String


  def generate_slug_from_tag
    self.slug = self.name.downcase.gsub(' ','-')
  end


  def to_param
    self.slug
  end
end
```

**View**

```
 <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
 <%= link_to tag.name,tag_id_path(tag.slug),class: 'label label-default' %>
 <% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
  get "/tags", to: "tag#index", as: "tags_index"

  get "/tags/new", to: "tag#new", as: "tags_new"
  post "/tags/new", to: "tag#create"
  get "/tags/:slug", to:"tag#show", as: "tag_id"


  get "/tags/:id/edit", to: "tag#edit", as: "tags_edit"
  patch "/tags/:id", to: "tag#update"
  put "/tags/:id", to: "tag#update"
  delete "/tags/:id", to: "tag#destroy"
```

Comment: We're also missing your routes file...

Comment: You can replace most of that mess with just the line `resouces :tags`

Comment: Your routes config would help. I suspect that you have something like

resources :tags do
  resources :something
  resources :sports
end